# Angular5 providers based DI issue

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular5

I have a custom class (non module) in angular 5, i would like to use this class implements the `CanActivate` interface because i would like to use this as [route guard](https://angular.io/guide/router).

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class TokenRequiredRouteGuard  implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private router: Router){}

    canActivate(){
        let token = localStorage.getItem('token');
        if(!token){
            this.router.navigate['/splashpage'];
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

In the AppModule i add the class in the providers section so to make it picked up by angular's DI:

```
    NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SplashpageComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes,{ useHash: true }),
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    CalendarModule,

  ],
  providers: [TokenRequiredRouteGuard],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],

})
```

But then when this route comes to action at run time i get:

```
core.js:1448 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[TokenRequiredRouteGuard]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[TokenRequiredRouteGuard]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for TokenRequiredRouteGuard!
Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[TokenRequiredRouteGuard]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[TokenRequiredRouteGuard]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for TokenRequiredRouteGuard!
```

I have found several incidents on github opened for similar problems but they all refer to adding the import in the `imports` section in `@NgModule` but my class isn't a module.
Any idea what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accoring to the documentation you posted above, you are supposed to provide the CanActivate implementation as follows:

```
import { TokenRequiredRouteGuard}                from '../tokenRequiredRouteGuard.service';

const routesConfig: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent,
    canActivate: [TokenRequiredRouteGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        children: [
          { path: 'test1', component: Test1},
          { path: 'test2', component: Test2}
        ],
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routesConfig)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

i.e. you are not supposed to declare it as a provided, but rather provide it as a router configuration for the property "canActivate"